# authenticating a fusion table update or insert row

Tags: google-maps, coldfusion, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google map I created using a fusion table that show our club locations and I am trying to update with query's within my websites code. Up until now we have had to create a new fusion table every time we want to update our map. The ultimate goal is to have it update at least once a month updating old info and adding new clubs. This is the live page i would eventually like to be able to do this on http://www.optimist.org/join.cfm

```
<cfhttp  url="https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"  method="post" charset="utf-8">
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="accountType" value="GOOGLE"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Email" value="Email"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Passwd" value="*Password"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="accountType" value="GOOGLE"></cfhttpparam>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="service" value="fusiontables"></cfhttpparam>
</cfhttp>

<cfoutput>
    #cfhttp.fileContent#
</cfoutput>

<cfset authToken = listtoarray(cfhttp.FileContent,"=")[4]>
<br /><br /><cfoutput>#authToken#</cfoutput><br /><br />

<cfhttp method="post" url="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query" charset="utf-8">
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="sql" value="INSERT INTO 17FBjtJoIQBK9ukBHTFlGmqX-DJRojZ4J9II2M3na (FullAddress, NbrOfMbrs) VALUES ('4494 Lindell Blvd St Louis MO 63108 United States', 11);"/>
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin auth=#authToken#"/>
</cfhttp>

<cfoutput>
    #cfhttp.fileContent#
</cfoutput>
```

This is what I get back

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", 
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.", 
"extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Daily 
Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." } }
```

Comment: @Kasiya I've not used Google's fusion maps, but typically API requests for google also require a "developers key" - I'm not seeing that in your POST request.  Also, getting this header right might be tricky - make sure you trap the request at look at it carefully. In this example (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/apps_script) they are writing the header directly. It seems to match yours above but everything could be important (extra spaces, case etc).

Comment: thank you for the link I guess what I am really wondering is how can I break down the response to separate parts so I can understand it better

Comment: I guess i will just keep searching the web as my second attempt to find an answer has also gone unnoticed. I did however find a code that appears to authorize my account, but I now am stuck with where i would place my insert into sql statement. Here is the code i found to use... [link]https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js